# BizTalk custom pipeline component values to orchestration

Tags: c#, biztalk, custom-pipeline-component

I have a requirement to get two values (Username, Password) from a receive pipeline component and use those two values in an orchestration. I have created the pipeline component with a Wizard and the relevant parts of the code is shown below:

```
public class AccountDetails : Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IComponent, IBaseComponent, IPersistPropertyBag, IComponentUI
    {
        
        private System.Resources.ResourceManager _resourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("PipelineComponentsAccountDetails.AccountDetails", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        private string _userName;
        private string _password;
        
        //private static bool DPM32;

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return _userName;
            }
            set
            {
                _userName = value;
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return _password;
            }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
            }
        }

...

public virtual void Load(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPropertyBag propertyBag, int errorLog)
        {
            object val = null;
            val = this.ReadPropertyBag(propertyBag, "UserName");
            if ((val != null))
            {
                this._userName = ((string)(val));
            }

            val = this.ReadPropertyBag(propertyBag, "Password");
            if ((val != null))
            {
                this._password = ((string)(val));
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the current component configuration into the property bag
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyBag">Configuration property bag</param>
        /// <param name="clearDirty">not used</param>
        /// <param name="saveAllProperties">not used</param>
        public virtual void Save(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPropertyBag propertyBag, bool clearDirty, bool saveAllProperties)
        {
            this.WritePropertyBag(propertyBag, "UserName", this.UserName);
            this.WritePropertyBag(propertyBag, "Password", this.Password);
        }

...

public Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage Execute(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext pContext, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage pInMsg)
        {
            // 
            // TODO: implement component logic
            // 
            // this way, it's a passthrough pipeline component
            return pInMsg;
        }
```

To be honest with you, I am not sure what I am doing. First and foremost, is this the correct way of, for lack of a better word, setting things up? Anyone knows a good tutorial?

As you can see the Execute does nothing but return the message. So how can I get these two values to the orchestration? I am a bit afraid that this will affect the solution since my assignment is to fetch AD data via a LDAP request.

Since one of the fields is a password, some sort of masking would have been good (not sure if this is something can be set in VS during coding?)

Please let me know if you need more information from me.

Edit:

I have created a property schema (PropertySchema.xsd) with two fields, UserName and Password. Those two fields have the setting 'Property Schema Base' set to 'MessageContextPropertyBase'.

In the custom pipeline component I do the promotion like this:

```
public Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage Execute(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext pContext, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage pInMsg)
        {
            // 
            // TODO: implement component logic
            // 
            // this way, it's a passthrough pipeline component

            // To make use of the properties in an orchestration
            pInMsg.Context.Promote("UserName", "https://xxx.INTxxx_HR_xxx_to_xxx.Schemas.PropertySchema", UserName);
            pInMsg.Context.Promote("Password", "https://xxx.xxx_HR_xxx_to_xxx.Schemas.PropertySchema", Password);
            return pInMsg;
        }
```

I believed that I would be able to use that schema in a message but that property schema is not available to pick to the message. So how do you go about to do the last thing so that I am able to be able to use them in the orchestration?

Comment: From what I can read. you are on the correct way. I would "promote the values to the context" (2 lines of code, 1 for each value). Then you can read those properties again when you are in the orchestration. And like already done in above code, just return the message as is. For the 'secure part', read up on 'trusted' and 'untrusted' hosts. Then promote with secret mode.

Comment: Hi, @MarvinSmit. I don't get this. I have created everything as I think it is supposed to be. But I am not able to access the two properties I need. Would you care to take a look? I will show my changes in the Edit-part of the original question.

Comment: Looks good to me. Now you can access these in your orchestration by: 
MessageReceived( xxx.xxx_HR_xxx_to_xxx.Schemas.PropertySchema.UserName )

Where the xxx.xxx_HR_... is your property schema's ,net class name. (FQN)

Comment: Thank you, @MarvinSmit. With your help I managed. Really appreicated, mate!

Comment: You, Sir, are welcome! Happy messaging!

Comment: @MarvinSmit You should post your comments as an answer, so it can be accepted.